# JavaScript axios options

Tags: axios

I defined options parameter in const.js. Below is the code.
I tried to get V1LOGIN from const.js above and send an axios request, but the error above "ReferenceError: Options is not defined" appears. Please solve the above problem

```
### const.js
const { address, username, password, uuid } = require("/data/options.json").server;

const V1LOGIN = {
    "url": `http://${address}/webapp/data/getLoginWebApp.php`,
    "method": "GET",
    "params": {
        "device": "WA",
        "login_ide": username,
        "login_pwd": password
    }
};

###server.js
const axios = require("axios");
const {
    V1LOGIN,
} = require("./const.js");

class hdcServer {
    constructor() {
        this.logger = require("./logger.js");
        this.rs485 = require("../bestin.js");
    }

    async serverLogin(time) {
        this.logger.info(`server login ===> ${JSON.stringify(V1LOGIN)}`);

        try {
            const response = await axios(V1LOGIN);

            if (time === "refresh") {
                this.logger.info("IPARK v1 server session refreshing...");
            }

            if (time === "fresh") {
                this.logger.info("IPARK v1 server login successful!");
                this.logger.info(`server login <=== ${response.data}`);

                this.loginManagement(response, "v1", "fresh");
            } else {
                this.logger.info("IPARK v1 server session refresh successful!");
                this.logger.info(`server login <=== ${response.data}`);

                this.loginManagement(response, "v1", "refresh");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(`IPARK v1 server login fail. return with: ${error}`);
        }
    }
}
```